# Queries not called from other queries in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have to delete the queries I don't use any longer in Power Query. One way is to identify which query is not called by any other query (let's call it top query) and see if it is still needed. If it is not then I can delete it safely.

One way to achieve this is to go through each query and see if another query is called. If another query is called than that query is not a top query
Besides this manual method, is there a better one ?

Comment: I don't believe you can delete a query if other queries are dependent upon it. In any event, on the `View` menu, there is a `Query Dependencies tab which may give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If a query is being referenced by another query, it won't let you delete it. Thats the best way to trace things back other then looking at code